# Android Studio Multi Module Project Gradle Sync Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm creating a multimodule project with an app module, a server module and a shared module. When I run ./gradlew build in the LetsGo root directory it returns without any errors.
If I open the project in android studio though I'm getting some weird errors and my design editor isn't showing anything because of an incorrect sync. Even though everything in the sync tab gets a green checkmark, it still spits out errors. I invalidated the caches already, but that's not helping. I'm trying to give as much information as possible, so the next part might be a bit long. But I think I ordered them in what is most to least relevant.

The sync errors:

On the project LetsGo:

```
Gradle Daemon started in 876 ms
<ij_msg_gr>Other<ij_msg_gr><ij_nav>/Users/koen/Vakken/Architecture_and_design/letsgo/LetsGo/app/build.gradle<ij_nav><i><b>project ':app': Unable to resolve all content root directories</b><eol>Details: java.lang.NullPointerException: null</i>
<ij_msg_gr>Tests model errors<ij_msg_gr><ij_nav>/Users/koen/Vakken/Architecture_and_design/letsgo/LetsGo/app/build.gradle<ij_nav><i><b>project ':app'</b><eol>Details: java.lang.NullPointerException: null</i>

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 9s
```

On the project :server (even though I don't think this should be a different sync)

```
Task 'wrapper' not found in project ':server'.
```

Error log is at https://pastebin.com/nq6HpmGi

in gradle.properties I set the following variables:

```
kotlin_version=1.3.61
gradle_version=3.6.1
```

`./gradlew projects` output

```
Root project 'LetsGo'
+--- Project ':app'
+--- Project ':common'
\--- Project ':server'
```

Quick dump of my gradle files:

settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':common', ':server'
rootProject.name='LetsGo'
```

build.gradle

LetsGo

```
buildscript {
    ...

    dependencies {
        // Gradle/Kotlin Core
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    group 'com.kvw.letsgo'
    version '0.0.1'
    repositories {
        ...
    }
}

project(':app') {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
}

project(':server'){
    repositories {
        ...
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

:server

```
plugins{
    id 'kotlin'
    id 'application'
    ...
}

mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['testresources']
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

:app

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    ...
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kvw.letsgo.client"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ...
    }
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

    ...
}

dependencies {
    // Local
    implementation project(':common')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

And finally for completeness here's the output of `tree LetsGo -L 2`

```
LetsGo
├── LetsGo.iml
├── app
│   ├── app.iml
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── libs
│   ├── proguard-rules.pro
│   └── src
├── build
│   ├── intermediates
│   └── kotlin
├── build.gradle
├── common
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── common.iml
│   ├── libs
│   └── src
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── local.properties
├── server
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── resources
│   ├── server.iml
│   ├── src
│   └── test
├── settings.gradle
└── versions.gradle
```

Comment: Found part of it! The server project was apparently wrongfully added in .idea/gradle.xml

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it's a long time ago
I since then found out it's better to have twoo projects (server and client) that both include the same kotlin multiplatform library
It was a lot of fidgetting around with settings, and you have to make sure everything is build with gradle (and not intellijs building mechanic)